# Geocodin process in open source GIS tools

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis

I want to do geocoding with open source gis tools , is it possible? if then tell me the solution?
I have my village attribute data with me like addresses and contact information of persons in every house. Now I want to do a small project with all details by using google imagery with open source gis tool? Let me explain?

Comment: We already have the answers for you: [search our site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=geocoding+open+source)!

Answer (score 2):

In the QGIS plugin mmqgis there is a function to geocode an imported csv based on street and city attributes. 
For any further help you need to provide more details (your question is not precise enough regarding what you want from which data)